# Escape the regex character from a Searching String

Tags: java, regex, string

We use a Regex for matching text such as follow

```
       String  str =".*" + s + ".*";
```

here -  s is user enter text

```
  if(stringtext.matches(str .toLowerCase())){
           return true;
   }
```

above code is working fine when user enter plain text.
but user enter any regex character such as e.g. (,},},^,$ etc 
it gives
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 5 .*(.*

Comment: I want exscape Regx character in matches(stringtext)